# Access computed object prop in another computed in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm getting an unexpected `undefined` when I attempt to show the message in a script setup like this:

```html
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const message = computed(() => {
  return {
    body: 'howdy'
  }
})

const msg = computed(() => {
  return message.body
})
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>
```

Granted this is a simplified/contrived example, but `message` works, `message.value` works, but `message.body` or `message.body.value` are undefined. How can I access the props of the object returned in the other computed property from `msg`?

[Playground Link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kM2OwjAMhF/FyqUgLYn2WpVK+x65lNa0RZsfxe4iFOXd16WAOHHzKJPPM87qJ0b9t6CqVUN9miMDIS+xtX52MSSGDH1wcWEcoMA5BQeV+Cvrre+DJwaHRN2IcHwZd7s9HFvI1gMkoSW/zQCnMNxqqKZwHW6CACjWl/0bi8bPnMcyvYK2r43ZcktiEYwu/naMogCa6bvN+Q4tpTGiVvvLor7U1vHguqgvFLxc4b7MPh7IqvoZ3SqpvWqrJuZItTF07tfbXUiHNBqZdFo8zw41kjucUrgSJgFb9ayqyj/QR3+x)

Comment: Did you think about using `message.value.body` ? Computed function returns `Ref<T>` object. To read it in script tag, always use `.value` first. Template no need `.value`.

Comment: Clearly I did not. Rookie mistake... thanks